# Do a semiinfinite line has zero Hausdorff dimension?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

I read that if a fractal is a union of N copies of itself, each copy shrunk by a factor of $1/z$; this yields a Hausdorff dimension of $D=ln(N)/ln(z)$

If a finite segment of (straight) line $[a,b]$ is scaled down by $n$, you need $n^1$ copies of the scaled version to match the original line segment, so the Hausdorff dimension of the line is $D=log(n^1)/log(n)=1$. The dimension is $D=1$

But if instead of a finite segment, it is a semi infinite line $[a,\infty]$, then scaling it down by any positive real number produces again a semi infinite line, then you only need 1 copy of the scaled version to fill the original. $D=log(1)/log(n)=0$

Does that means that the Hausdorff dimension of the semi infinite line is D=0?

If not, then what is the right answer, and why?

Comment: How did you produce the argument in the first paragraph of your question? I ask because already that argument already seems to have little to do with the usual concept of Hausdorff dimension https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension

Comment: @Lee Mosher. I read that if a fractal is a union of N copies of itself, each copy shrunk by a factor of $1/z$; this yields a Hausdorff dimension of $D=ln(N)/ln(z)$

Comment: So that's an extremely rough statement, and not really useful in the situation you ask about. For one thing, it applies only locally, i.e. only to finite diameter metric spaces. For another, it has many more hypotheses than you have indicated.

Comment: @Lee Mosher I read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension#Role_of_scaling and I need clarification. I didn't made any hypotheses.

Comment: The informal discussion in that article is based on finite values. But you are trying to stuff infinite numbers in it without any thought as to how it should work. It is no wonder you get ridiculous results.

Comment: As for the right answer, it is still $1$. Dimension is not about extent.